# How to Edit and update the td in a table in js

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

Need to Edit and update the td in the table. I need to edit the table when I click the "edit" button, and similarly update it on clicking the save.

```
function editCell(e) {
  var t = document.getElementById("table");
  var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var tds = null;
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    tds[3].appendChild(firstname);  
  tds.innerHTML = firstname.value;

  tds[4].appendChild(lastname);  
  tds.innerHTML = lastname.value;

  tds[5].appendChild(email);  
  tds.innerHTML = email.value;

  tds[6].appendChild(phnumber);  
  tds.innerHTML = phnumber.value;

}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajaovi/7avhfjv2/)

Comment: Does [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/7avhfjv2/1/) achieve the first part of what you wanted? If so I can help with the save part if you want.

Comment: Yes Gregory This is what I want..yes Gregory I need the save part too. And I want to save the edited td with new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** Consider the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/7avhfjv2/3/) with your solution. The following function "saves" the data to the td.

```
function saveCell() {...}
```

**Note:** If you want to physically save it somewhere you would need to use a server side language such as PHP.